# Is the minimum point of a strictly convex function stable?

Tags: convex-optimization

This is a problem I figured out after seeing the definition of minimum stable point and I think the following tense is true:

> Let $f(x)$ be a strictly convex function whose minimum values is $f^*=f(x^*)$. Show that $x^*$ is a stable minimum point.

Here $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

**Definition:** A minimum point $x^*$ is said to be stable if for every minimizing sequence $f(x^k)\rightarrow f^*$ it follows that $x^k\rightarrow x^*$.

I tried to use the convexity and contradiction whit $\|x^k-x^*\|\geq \varepsilon>0$, but I can't finish it. Thanks.

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: Convex function on an open finite dimensional domain is continuous

Comment: Yes, I know, but i dont figure out how to use it yet

Comment: $x^k$ has a convergent subsequence or a subsequence whose norm diverges to infinity. Try to obtain a contradiction in the first case if the limit is not the minimum.